# insert data from one table to another table table name genrated runtime without declaring the table fields

Tags: sql-server

I have two table say table1 and table2 all the columns in both table are same but table2 has some extra column in which i want to insert a some default value and name of table is generated runtime so table name can be changed so i cant declare the field of table.

Comment: great...what you've tried?

Comment: If you just need to default the field values, try looking up default constraints.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking how to create a table with a dynamic name? Or with dynamic columns? Or how to set default values on a table? Or generating an `INSERT` query dynamically? Or something else? And are you trying to do this in TSQL itself or from some application code? Please give a more precise explanation, and showing some code would probably be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is **dynamic query**.

Please have a look at the code below

```
create table #temp1(id int, prodName varchar(max))

insert into #temp1 values(1,'a')
insert into #temp1 values(2,'b')
insert into #temp1 values(3,'c')
insert into #temp1 values(4,'d')


declare @TableName varchar(20)
set @TableName='NewTable';
declare @QueryCreateTable varchar(max);

set @QueryCreateTable = 
'create table ' + @TableName + ' (id int, prodName varchar(max), defaultCol int DEFAULT 0) 
insert into ' + @TableName + ' (id,prodName)
(
select * from #temp1
)
select * from ' + @TableName;


exec (@QueryCreateTable);

drop table #temp1
```

Comment: thanx saksham but this wont be work both table is present in database  and table name is genrating runtime i.e if firt time table name is table1 and table2 next time table can be table3 and table4 which has different fields

Answer (score 0):

I have written answer to your question. you can view in the following [link](http://droiddddd.blogspot.in/2013/02/insert-data-from-one-table-to-another.html).

Also FYI. If you pass the parameter of source and destination to proc, it will automatically insert the data from source to destination.